# Best way for user controls to communicate within the form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, datatable

I had a full paragraph of moaning which is now removed. So I cut to the chase:

1. How can I notify `userControlA` that a button has been clicked in `userControlB`?
2. How can I notify the main form that a button has been clicked in `userControlA`?

Is the answer provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153710/communicating-from-to-usercontrol-in-tabcontrol-in-form) the best solution? I'm looking for the best solution.

Comment: Create an event + listener. Subscribe to (listen for) the event in the main form/other usercontrol

Comment: @DGibbs like the one provided in the linked post you mean? Is that what you recommend or do you have a simpler approach. Because there will be many listeners and events. What's the advantage of this over one giant class divided into partial classes. Everyone will recognize everyone else. That's pretty much my main question.

Comment: When you say "there will be many listeners and events": maybe you only need one event for each user control and then pass some information with the event about e.g. which button was pressed.

Comment: Think about user control as a normal control (to example, `Button`). When you want to know if specific button is clicked in `userControlB`, then create an event, so that anyone (to example, form) can subscribe to it. You can have just one event for multiple changes, if, to example, you simply want to inform listener "hey, something changed, please check all my properties again".

Comment: @Sinatr can you give a more solid example of "just one event for multiple" changes? Is the one provided in the link a good example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example

```
public partial class UserControlA
{

    // method to inform
    public void DoSomething(string text)
    {
        ... // do something with text
    }
}

public partial class UserControlB
{
    public event Action SomethingChanged;
    public string SomeText {get; set;} // some property

    private void button1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(SomethingChanged != null)
            SomethingChanged(); 
    }
}

// in form contructor (for demonstration purpose)
var a = new UserControlA();
var b = new UserControlB();
this.Controls.Add(a);
this.Controls.Add(b);
var handler = () => a.DoSomething(b.SomeText);
b.SomethingChanged += handler;
```

Now, when you click `button1` in `UserControlB`, then `UserControlA` get its `DoSomething()` method called. Form is used to pass event, but you can subscribe to event in `UserControlA` directly, you will need to pass instance of `UserControlB` somehow (property, method, constructor).